# document.styleSheets returns nothing

Tags: javascript, firefox, css

I am using css3 animations to move items from one side of the screen to the other. I want to make sure this effect works regardless of screen resolution. In order to do this, I use `document.styleSheets` in order to get access to the css file with all of the animation keyframes and change their final values.

Here is the js code I am using:

```
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[1];

var rules = stylesheet.rules;
var keyframes;
var keyframe;

for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
    keyframes = rules.item(i);

    var keyframeRules = keyframes.cssRules;
    var j = keyframeRules.length;
    var index = i+1;

    while (j--) {
        keyframe = keyframeRules.item(j);
        if (keyframe.keyText === "100%") {
            if(keyframe.style.left != ''){
                keyframe.style.left = $(document).width() + $('#cloud'+ index).width() + 'px';
            }
        }
    }

    $('#cloud'+ index).addClass('animating');
}
```

The css file I am using contains:

```
@-moz-keyframes cloud1 {
0%{ left: -400px; }
100%{ left: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud1 {
0%{ left: -400px; }
100%{ left: 0; }
}
```

I have quite a few pairs of keyframes in there.

My problem is `document.styleSheets` returns an empty css file if I `console.log` it and inspect in firebug. As a result, `rules.length` is null. Webkit based browsers work without any issues.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: in firefox, it seems that .cssRules works and .rules does not. Try this.

Also try `var stylesheet = document.styleSheets;` and then accessing the stylsheet variable using a specific index.

Comment: The second part seems to half work. It gives me the two css files but if then try to access the second css file using the index, it gives me nothing again. Here is a screenshot of what firebug gives me if I do `console.log(document.styleSheets)` - http://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Omc.png

Comment: The spec says the property is called `cssRules`.

Comment: I have a similar a problem where `document.styleSheets.length` was something like `50` before, but after manipulating just one rule it became something like `4`. (numbers vary). Happens to me in Brave (Chromium derivative). Very inconsistent. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers use different names to refer to those rules.

Here's how I handle this problem in my code :

```
var cssRules = stylesheet.rules; // chrome, IE
if (!cssRules) cssRules = stylesheet.cssRules; // firefox (and maybe Chrome too in recent versions)
```

You could do it as :

```
var cssRules = stylesheet.rules || stylesheet.cssRules;
```

But I prefer the first version as it's clearer.

Comment: My problem is `stylesheet` seems to be blank. If I just do `document.styleSheets` without an index then I get http://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Omc.png but as soon as I try to use an index to get at `animation.css`, I get nothing again.

Comment: `document.styleSheets[1].cssRules` gives the expected output even though `document.styleSheets[1]` gives nothing - how very odd.

Comment: Isn't this more a Firebug problem than a browser one ?